# MongoDB UpdateOne with an specific Upsert behaviour

Tags: mongodb

this is the behaviour that I'm looking for:

1- Update the database, filtering by unique id, in case does not exist create new document(all the fields).

2- If the document exists, only update one especific field.

The problem that I encounter is that if I use:

```
collection.update_one( {'id':document['id']},
{"$set":{'field_to_update':document['field_to_update']}}, upsert:True)
```

Whenever the document does not exist it will create a new document but only with the field_to_update as its content. And I need to update only a field(this is because there are fields that changes a lot and I'm not interested to update) but on the other case create a complete document.

Does anyone how to achieve this?

Regards.

Comment: I think you will have to do it conditionally. I believe, you are using PyMongo driver?

Comment: Yes PyMongo, I see thanks.

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works, you'd "accept"/"upvote" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **$setOnInsert** to add extra fields when a new document is inserted due to upsert, Try to use it with UpdateOne if it doesn't, you can use a query like below sample

```
 collection.findAndModify({
    'query': { 'id':document['id'] },
    'update': {
        "$set":{'field_to_update':document['field_to_update']},
        '$setOnInsert': {
            'field_to_add': document['field_to_add'],
            'field_to_add_more': document['field_to_add_more']
            }
        },
    'new': True,
    'upsert': True,
})
```

Comment: Happy to help :)